# Cmake build problem with opencv (error LNK2019) in vscode

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, cmake, linker-errors

So I've been trying to get started on opencv c++. I followed a tutorial on how to set it up, [link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9HBM1m_EMU&ab_channel=TheCodingLib). I wrote a simple opencv script for an image display. I built the project after that and I got this error:

```
[build] main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::Mat(void)" (??0Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
[build] main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
[build] main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class cv::Mat & __cdecl cv::Mat::operator=(class cv::Mat &&)" (??4Mat@cv@@QEAAAEAV01@$$QEAV01@@Z) referenced in function main
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\opencv.dir\build.make:152: opencv.exe] Error -1
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:838: CMakeFiles/opencv.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:120: all] Error 2
[build] main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function main
[build] main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function main
[build] main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function main
[build] main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@@Z) referenced in function main
[build] opencv.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

I did some research but most of the answers were for Visual Studio users and I'm using vscode, not that. Here's how my CMakeLists.txt look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(opencv VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(opencv main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

How can I fix this error and what was the cause of it? By the way, I'm using VS Build tools 2019.

**Edit:**

So I tried changing my Cmake kit to my usual compiler, MingW64 and the code seems to be compiling fine. The error only really happens with the Visual Studio C++ compiler. Why does it only happen to the VS compiler though?

Comment: As it seems mingw gives the error? unfortunately, you cannot use the prebuilt libs with mingw, they are for msvc only. You have to build them from source by yourself if you want to use with another compiler.